# how to make a std list of a class that contains unique pointers

Tags: c++, list, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm trying to make a std list that will hold a list of classes that contain a unique pointer. I keep getting an error that says attempting to reference a deleted function.

I understand that the problem is that unique pointers don't have an assignment operator and list is trying to call it, but I can't figure out a way around this.

Here is the code for the class that holds the pointer:

```
class ptr_hold
{
public:
    ptr_hold(std::list<int>& _lst);
    std::list<int>* get_list();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::list<int>> num_list;
};

ptr_hold::ptr_hold(std::list<int>& _lst)
{
    num_list = std::unique_ptr<std::list<int>>(new std::list<int>(_lst));
}
```

Here is the example code trying to do the assigment:

```
list<int> lst;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    lst.push_back(i);
}
ptr_hold ph = ptr_hold(lst);

list<ptr_hold> ph_list;
ph_list.push_back(ph); //error
ph_list.push_back(move(ph)); //error
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: `ph_list.emplace_back(lst);`

Comment: Actually, `ph_list.push_back(move(ph));` works fine for me. But `emplace_back` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a good chance that you are using VS, since it doesn't automagically generate move member functions for you. (Otherwise `ph_list.push_back(move(ph))` would work.)

The `unique_ptr` does have move-assignment operator, which implies ownership transfer. To call move-assignment operator (or move constructor for that matter) you need to work with rvalue. (`T&&`, where `T` is not meant as template here, as that invokes something a bit different) To obtain a rvalue, you either have to work with a temporary (such as a return value from a function) or you have to manually cast lvalue to rvalue. This is done via `std::move` (to signify intent) or a bit more wordy `static_cast`.

To solve this, either use `emplace_back` or declare proper constructors manually, and use either `emplace_back` or `push_back(move())`.

---edit---
*Note: `emplace_back` probably shouldn't require move-assignment constructor to work, but you will run into trouble when trying to extract the object from the list.*

Comment: @dyp Noted and changed, thanks. Also I swear I started with the answer before your comment.

Comment: Btw you don't need to add "--edit--" or "\[edit\]" when editing parts of your answer, there's a [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21818780/revisions), and there's a notifier for others when reading the answer and it just has been edited.

Comment: @dyp I know, but I feel that it serves a purpose of quickly visually indicating a change that should be noted in the post, or perhaps a later thought-of note/remark. (Or perhaps I am rationalizing a habit from different forums. :-) )

Comment: I tried emplace_back with and without the move function, but that didn't work for me. I'm not familiar with the rvalue, so I'm reading up on that now.